# How to use post type as form data in Python using Zabbix Api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, zabbix

I'm using the below script to create a form but its creating step scene as raw data.
I tried to select post type as Form data in step but it is not working as expected. Please guide me. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

code:

```
http = self.zapi.httptest.create(name = web_data,hostid=hostid,delay='2m',applicationid=appid,
            steps=[{'name':web_data,'url':web_data,'status_codes':'200','posts':['name','','value',''],'no':1}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'array of HTTP fields', but you are using an array. Try with:

```
'posts': [
  {'name': 'the field', 'value': 'the content'},
  {'name': 'another field', 'value': 'another content'}
]
```

Documentation: [httptest/object](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/httptest/object)